# Best option to implement external register/login to WP from self-made API

Tags: login, user-registration, api, rest-api

Hi everyone and thank you in advance for reading the question and helping me out.

I amb building with a friend an app that uses a custom self-made PHP-MySQL API to be cross-platform. Everything in the app works thanks to that API but we need users to be controlled by an external WP. **WP and API are in different sub-domains and servers.**

So we have: WP (for users) + API (for functionalities and data) + Apps (UIs).

Users write it's credentials in the App and that credentials go to our own API and here is where I doubt how should I use those credentials to log in into WP. The same happends to register. Those two functionalities need to be handled by WP and I don't know which of this 2 options is best:

**Option 1:** Create another mini-api for WP with wp_create_user() and others needed and call from the main API to the mini-api for WP to regiser / login

**Option 2:** Use WP Rest API to authenticate and register. *The problem with that option is that all the examples that I have seen were web-based and **I need to implement it with no grafic interfice to call it from my PHP API***.

**Response needed:** In any case the only answer I need from WP is the **wp_user id**.

PD: Sorry for my poor english, it's not my native language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Why create your own WordPress API (mini or not) when you already have one?

**Option 2**: You should try to extend the WordPress REST API in order to register/authenticate. You can use, e.g. https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/ or just grab from it the code you need and modify it.

Comment: Thank you very much David! That plugin seems to have everything I need!